# How to plot a function using a table particular values

Tags: plotting, replacement, list-manipulation, legending

I would like to plot the following function in terms of kR, but using specific different values, I think the best easy way is using a Table. This is a common useful problem to explore numerical the behavior in a particular function, this is the code

```
k = 2 Pi; R = 1; 
f =  Sin[ Sqrt[π] /Sqrt[ n k R] ] E^(-((I k (R^2 + z^2))/(2 R))) ;
```

Change R, this code generates `k R= 2Pi, 3 Pi, 4 Pi`. But,  The idea is to plot , let say plot  `k R = 2Pi, 50 Pi`, and `100 Pi`

Of course it is simple for this case since could be evaluated, and show a legend. Interesting suggestions are welcome, thanks

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Re[f], {n, 3}]], {z, 0, 20}, 
Filling -> Axis, 
PlotRange -> All, 
AxesLabel -> {z, f }]
```

Comment: `f = Sin[Sqrt[\[Pi]]/Sqrt[n k R]] E^(-((I k (R^2 + z^2))/(2 R)));
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Re[f], {n, 3}] /. {k -> 2, R -> 3}], {z, 0, 20}, 
 Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {z, f}]`

Comment: Changing the last `Table` argument from `{n, 3}` to `{n, {1, 25, 50}}` will produce curves with amplitudes of `Sqrt[Pi] / Sqrt[ n k R ]` for $n\, k\, R = 2\pi, 50\pi \text{ and } 100\pi$.  However, the phase of the exponential will still have $k=2\pi, R=1$.